# Is it possible to change domparser element to string?

Tags: javascript, document, domparser, document.write

I have some HTML string. Use domparser to update some values, now i need back to HTML string format with updated values... Bcoz document.write accept only string.

Checkout the Sample patch,

```
const domName = 'MOBILE_NO';
// Below dom was getting from api.
const dom =  '<html><head><title>Merchant Checkout Page</title></head><body><center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center><form method="post"  name="paytm_form"><input type="hidden" name="MOBILE_NO" value="xxxxxxxx"></form></body></html>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(dom, 'text/html');
parsedHtml.getElementsByName(domName)[0].setAttribute('value', '1234567890');

// now i need to replace current update data entire screen
document.write(parsedHtml)
```

Thanks,

Gopal.R

Comment: *"Bcoz document.write accept only string."* Using `document.write` is almost always poor practice. Why do you think you need to?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i agree, is there any option available let me know, this is payment gateway integrations html coming from api some of element values are encrypted before render i need to decrpyt replace this, it will automatcally take into paytm screen.

Comment: `element1.appendChild(element2.outerHTML);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Bcoz document.write accept only string.

Using `document.write` is almost always poor practice.

**But**, if for some reason you really need to, what you get back from `parseFromString` is a [`Document` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document). It has a single `documentElement`, which you can get the `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` of:

```
document.write(parsedHtml.documentElement.innerHTML);
// or
document.write(parsedHtml.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

Live Example:

```js
const domName = 'MOBILE_NO';
// Below dom was getting from api.
const dom =  '<html><head><title>Merchant Checkout Page</title></head><body><center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center><form method="post"  name="paytm_form"><input type="hidden" name="MOBILE_NO" value="xxxxxxxx"></form></body></html>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(dom, 'text/html');
parsedHtml.getElementsByName(domName)[0].setAttribute('value', '1234567890');

// now i need to replace current update data entire screen
document.write(parsedHtml.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

**But**, again, probably better to just append to the page, e.g.

```
document.body.appendChild(parsedHtml.documentElement);
```

Live Example:

```js
const domName = 'MOBILE_NO';
// Below dom was getting from api.
const dom =  '<html><head><title>Merchant Checkout Page</title></head><body><center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center><form method="post"  name="paytm_form"><input type="hidden" name="MOBILE_NO" value="xxxxxxxx"></form></body></html>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(dom, 'text/html');
parsedHtml.getElementsByName(domName)[0].setAttribute('value', '1234567890');

document.body.appendChild(parsedHtml.documentElement);
```

Or loop through it and append its children:

```
let child = parsedHtml.documentElement.firstChild;
while (child) {
    let next = child.nextSibling;
    document.documentElement.appendChild(child);
    child = next;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const domName = 'MOBILE_NO';
// Below dom was getting from api.
const dom =  '<html><head><title>Merchant Checkout Page</title></head><body><center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center><form method="post"  name="paytm_form"><input type="hidden" name="MOBILE_NO" value="xxxxxxxx"></form></body></html>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(dom, 'text/html');
parsedHtml.getElementsByName(domName)[0].setAttribute('value', '1234567890');

let child = parsedHtml.documentElement.firstChild;
while (child) {
    let next = child.nextSibling;
    document.documentElement.appendChild(child);
    child = next;
}
```

Comment: document.body.appendChild(parsedHtml.documentElement);

I have getting this error TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at KYCDemantAcOpenComponent.js:105

Comment: @Kitta - That's odd, but see the live example where I use the children instead. That's probably want you want anyway. (Running out the door I'm afraid, hopefully that helps.)

Comment: @TJ checking one it i hope it will work shortly update you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer would be another option.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks buddy. Its working cool.  document.write only i have used.